# How to slow down MonoGame

Tags: c#, sleep, monogame

I'm making a tile-based graphical roguelike game with MonoGame, and when handling input the player moves too fast. Moving the player with separate individual key presses does not make the application terribly fun to play.

How could I add some time between the game loops? When using `Thread.Sleep` the whole program gets stuck and doesn't handle any input.

Comment: The trick is not to add delay between game loop iterations, but to instead measure the time between loop executions and adjust time-dependent values (such as speed/velocity, acceleration, etc) accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I decided to do in the end.

I'm separating my game objects into components, and one is called Movement. Since the movement is tile-based, I couldn't use speeds or vectors or anything like that.

The code is simplified, I did not include everything here.

```
public class Movement 
{
    // define a movement interval and store the elapsed time between moves
    private double interval, elapsedTime;

    public Movement(double interval) 
    {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    // called when arrow keys are pressed (player)
    public void Move(Direction dir) 
    {
        if(elapsedTime > interval)
        {
            // move
        }
    }

    // called once per frame from the main class Update method
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if(elapsedTime > interval)
            elapsedTime -= interval;

        // add milliseconds elapsed during the frame to elapsedTime
        elapsedTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds; 
    }
}

public enum Direction 
{
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use doubles, floats are used for everything else in monogame and doubles use up twice as much memory (Hence the name "Double")

Answer (score 2):

The usual method is to define the speed of everything in "units per second".  So the player would move at a rate of 64 pixels per second (or whatever speed you choose).  Each frame, MonoGame will call `Update`, and pass in a `GameTime` instance with the amount of time that has passed since the last frame.  What you want to do is multiply the movement rate by `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`. So if 3/4th of a second passed since the last frame you would do `64 * .75` to get `48`, which is the number of pixels your should move your character that frame if the button is held down.

If you define everything in terms of "Units Per Second", you can easily keep speeds consistent regardless of how fast or slow your frame rate is.  This works for speed of movement (pixels/ meters per second), turning rate (degrees per second), health regeneration (hp per second), etc.  MonoGame makes it easy to do this, because all the fundamental units classes, like `Vector2` and `Vector3`, have their multiplication operators overloaded for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The extremely simple solution would be to decrease your fixed update rate that MonoGame defaults to. This makes your input less responsive though and is generally undesirable.

The better solution would be to calculate the elapsed time since the last update and adjust your movement accordingly. This also has the added benefit of making many more features easier, acceleration for example to give some weight to your objects can then be added as an integral of speed, or your framerate can be extended without having to buffer the last frame and extrapolating intermediary positions.